# Python Multi-processing architecture

Tags: python, multithreading, raspberry-pi, multiprocessing

I am actually doing a smart RC car demo with Raspberry Pi 3B, some sensors and actuators. 
Basically, the car should run autonomously in a controlled indoor environment: move autonomously while tracking a line on the ground and detecting, avoiding an obstacle on its way and taking a picture of the obstacle, etc.

My first idea of architecture looks like below (you can ignore the camera part): 
[image]

However, I think it is far from optimal of using a file in the middle to communicate between different processes.
As the sensors have different frequency to launch, I think multi-processing should probably solve the problem.
I did some search but am still not clear on how to architect it with multi-processing. 
Any advices would be really appreciated.

best regards,

Comment: I am not sure if using a shared_memory is the right direction? https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.shared_memory.html

Comment: tested redis also to share the memory between scripts.

Comment: Either you're confused, or I am, or we both are.  If you write e.g. ultrasonic.py then you can `import` that module into your controller.py and call any functions you need from there.  There is no need for each of the sensors to be running as a separate process (which can be done but I would advise against adding complexity before you need it).  Therefore, any "communication" can be done with normal function calls.

Comment: yes, I can import the module but I need all the sensors execute at the same time but with different frequency, if I execute them in one script, then they are in a sequential mode, the performance is poor. that's why I am looking for a multi-processing method which runs these processes parallelly, actually I find using Redis as a message broker could be a solution, want to know if there are better ones.